# show more button with PHP Mysql

Tags: php, mysql

I have a "show more" button to display 5 of last entries into database, with initial display of 1 record, like to change the initial variable to 3 results shown, here's my code:
$latest_entry_qry="SELECT *
                    FROM `cityres`
                    ORDER BY `id` DESC
                    LIMIT 0 , 5";

```
  $latest_entry=mysql_query($latest_entry_qry); 
   ?>
    <div id="just-head"> <b>Recently Added:</b></div>
    <div id="just-added">
      <?
 $modu = 1;
   while($latest_entry_row=mysql_fetch_array($latest_entry))
 {
       if($modu%5 == 1)
        $clsText = "";
      else
        $clsText = " class='show_more' style='display:none' ";
```

Comment: Please, don't use `mysql_*` functions to write new code. They are no longer maintained and the community has begun [deprecation process](http://goo.gl/q0gwD). See the [red box](http://goo.gl/OWwr2)? Instead you should learn about [prepared statements](http://goo.gl/orrj0) and use either [PDO](http://goo.gl/TD3xh) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli). If you can't decide which, [this article](http://goo.gl/YXyWL) will help you. If you pick PDO, [here is good tutorial](http://goo.gl/b2ATO). Also see [Why shouldn't I use mysql functions in PHP?](http://goo.gl/J5jAo)

Comment: any help with changing the initial variable ??

Answer (score 0):

Here is a guess as your `while` loop is incomplete. I am assuming at the end there is a -

```
$modu++;
```

since you are checking `$modu%5 == 1` every time in the `while` loop. if so, then you could just change it from

```
if($modu%5 == 1)
```

to

```
if($modu <=3)
```

Also, make note of @Daedalus comment about no longer using `mysql_*` functions

Comment: Glad I could help. Make sure you mark it as an accepted answer. [faq: how to accept an answer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work).